# Why am I getting the error "SDL_Event has not been declared"?

Tags: c++, sdl2

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. In my game.cpp, I have this:

```
void Game::input() {
    SDL_Event e;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {running=false; cout << "Quitting" << endl;}
        if(e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
            if(e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
            running=false;
            }
            moveSprite(e);
        }
        if(e.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
        }
        SDL_GetMouseState(&mousex, &mousey);
    }
}
```

In my player header file, I have:

```
class player {
public:
    player();
    int getPlayerX();  //get player's x position
    int getPlayerY();  //get player's y position
    void moveSprite( SDL_Event& e );
private:
    int xPos, yPos;
};
```

I'm getting the following error:

> SDL_Event has not been declared"

on the line: `void moveSprite( SDL_Event& e );`

It seems like something simple but I've been staring at it for hours and I can't figure it out. Be gentle, I'm a third semester programming student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't including `"SDL.h"`, you need to [forward-declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) the union. Do note that forward declaring is only possible when you're using the type as a reference or a pointer.

So here's what you need to add to the player header file before the player class:

`union SDL_Event;`

You could also just `#include "SDL.h"` in the header file, but it's generally a good idea to reduce the amount of includes in headers.